# Get test method for which configuration method was called in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

Is there a way to get `@Test` method reference from `ITestNGMethod` of a `@BeforeMethod`/`@AfterMethod` configuration method in TestNG? I know it is possible if corresponding configuration method declares a parameter of type `java.lang.reflect.Method` but I need a more generic solution which would work in listeners (`IInvokedMethodListener` or `IConfigurationListener`) even when there is no control on how configuration methods are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way in which a `@BeforeMethod`/`@AfterMethod` can get to know the `@Test` method for which it is going to be run, is by defining a `java.lang.reflect.Method` object as a parameter to the `@BeforeMethod`/`@AfterMethod` annotated configuration method. There is no other way in which you can extract out this information in a generic fashion (like using listeners) for e.g.,

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Krishnan. Is this something that could be added or is it impossible or very hard to implement with the current architecture?

Comment: @NebehrGudahtt - The problem is that, it cant be a generic solution (which is what will be expected even if it were to be addressed). You can perhaps log a bug in the TestNG github issues and we can perhaps discuss on this more there along and get inputs from Cedric and Julien

Comment: Now that https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2328 is implemented, do you think it is also possible to get access from configuration methods to the **parameters** the test method is being invoked with? Or is it impossible without further TestNG refactoring?